# Can't store field value from firestore to variable

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to store field value **name** read from a document in firestore **users** to variable **userName** so I can change the state value of userName. In general, how can I save field value to a variable and store it inside my component? Always, I appreciate everyone's help.

```
export default class Main extends Component {
state = {
    currentUser: null,
    userName: null
  };

getName = async () => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    this.setState({ currentUser });
    const uid = currentUser.uid;
    let userName = null;
    let docRef = await db.collection("users").doc(uid);
    docRef.get().then(doc => {
      userName = doc.data().name;
      console.log(userName);
      // this prints out "panda"
    });
    console.log(userName);
    // this prints out null
    this.setState({ userName });
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getName();
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower `console.log(userName)` prints null because your `await` is set on the assignment of the document ref, not on the `.get()`. `.doc()` returns a reference, whereas `.get()` returns a Promise.

This leads to your code not awaiting the Promise returned by `.get()` and moving passed that whole block, thereby showing a `null` value for `userName` since the Promise has not been resolved yet. There are a few different ways you can go about this. One way would be to put your `setState()` inside of the `.then()` block as in the following example:

Change your `getName()` to this:

```
getName = async () => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    this.setState({ currentUser });
    const uid = currentUser.uid;
    await db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
            if (doc && doc.exists) {
                this.setState({ userName: doc.data().name });
            }
        });
};
```

I left the `async/await` in there in case you will be adding further logic in this method which would need the firebase query to be awaited. If not, you can remove both the `async` and the `await`.

Comment: Thank you, what you suggested worked. Just out of curiosity, I deleted async and await and assigned doc.data().name to the local variable instantiated before query statement, but it still remained as null. Can you explain why this would happen?

Comment: if you want to set the variable outside of the scope of the `.then()` block then you'll need to keep the async/await, since you will need to wait for the promise to resolve before moving on with the rest of the code. If this answer was helpful, please consider setting it as the accepted answer :)